# Get AWS lambda response after Amazon S3 presigned URL upload

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

There is a use case I'm working on and I'm not quite sure how it can be solved. The main goal is to upload an image from a react native app to an Amazon S3 bucket using an AWS Lambda function (API Gateway) in order to use Amazon Rekognition service with another Amazon S3 image depending on some values sent to the lambda.

Since the image could be too large I have to use presigned URLs, which means that i make a request to the lambda to get a presigned S3 url to the client so that the client uploads the image to the bucket straight away. But then, how can i use face Rekognition service within the AWS Lambda?

I know i can trigger a lambda after an S3 upload, so i could do the face Rekognition request right after the user makes the http request with the presigned URL, but how can i get face Rekognition service response from that triggered lambda to the original user?
I've thought about SNS, but sending some text message to the user after an image upload instead of a message in the app seems odd.

Thank you in advance and apologies for the long read

Comment: Sadly you haven't provided much details. Is this web-application? How long does the upload take? Few minutes/seconds? Do users register to your service - you know exactly who uploaded what?

Comment: Its a mobile app (react native), and yes the user shall be logged in the app in order to send a picture. Its an app for the employees to clock in and out at work(by facial rekognition), so the whole process of uploading the image and process it should not take more than a few seconds.

Comment: Immediately following the successful S3 upload, your client could simply make another API call to your back-end which would trigger a different Lambda function that does the Rekognition work (face matching). The client would send it information identifying the uploaded image (bucket & key). The response would include the face match results. Also, be aware of another option which is that the client itself could invoke Rekognition directly via in-client AWS SDK, if needed, but it would have to get STS credentials from your back-end to do that.

Comment: I see no reason why you need to upload an image via a pre-signed URL. You can use the SDK to upload an image to an Amazon S3 bucket.

Comment: Hello @smac2020, Im kinda new to aws but I think i can only upload to s3 from user via a pre-signed URL unless I make my bucket public, so presigned-url is the safest way to do this, although i might be mistaken.

Comment: @CarlosIS You're correct. Having your bucket be public is a potential attack vector for any malicious users. Or just for trolls looking to drive up your S3 storage cost, just for fun...

Comment: @jarmod Thank you very much, i dont know why i didnt come to that conclusion but it seems very doable, doing the call to the api from the client after the s3 upload instead of triggering it by S3. Hopefully i'll manage to get it done.

Answer (score 3):

You're on the right track with SNS, maybe not with the service, but with the principal.

This is a problem of asynchronous handling of requests and how you can subsequently inform the user of the server's decision. To start, you're async process will need to store the result of the facial recognition somewhere, if you're already using a database (SQL or NoSQL), that would seem to be the place to do this.

Then you have to get the information to the user. Since your user is running a mobile application, there are only two ways of doing this. Either the user will have to poll the back-end service in order to retrieve the result of the async process, or your back-end will need to push the result to the device. Polling the service is straightforward and is usable depending on the load you expect from your application and the duration of the asynchronous process. You can also use long polling to reduce the number of requests, but this doesn't fix the issue (too many users spamming your service waiting for the result) itself.

If you want to notify the users, you will have to create a notification mechanism that is not based on polling a service. You could for example make use of WebSockets, configure your devices to have an MQTT connection (e.g., with AWS IoT) or use another cloud-based notification service that allows you to push messages to the device. You also do not have to include all the information in the message you push to your devices. The pushed message can be a trigger for the device to retrieve the result from the back-end service e.g., using an HTTP API.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, ill take a look into IoT services as i might need to use them in the nearby future.